# take $\int_\lambda f \ ds$ (Stieltjes) where $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\lambda(t) = (a\cos t, b\sin t)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, elliptic-integrals

> Calculate $\int_\lambda f \ ds$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$
>   is given by $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\lambda:[0,
>  2\pi]\to\mathbb{R^2}$ is the path $\lambda(t) = (a\cos t, b\sin t)$,
>   which describes an ellipse.

When $\lambda$ is $C^1$ and $w$ is a continuous $1-form$, we have:

$$\int_\lambda w =\int_a^b w(\lambda(t))\cdot \lambda'(t) dt$$

so:

$$\int_\lambda f\ ds = \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{(a\cos t)^2 + (b\sin t)^2}\cdot (-a\sin t, b\cos t) \ dt = \\ \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t} \cdot (-a\sin t, b\cos t) \ dt $$

but I can't even take the dot product... I don't hink this is the way to solve.

Comment: What you wrote is the definition of a line integral of a vector field $w$. This time, what you need is an integral of a scalar field. For that you need to compute the line element $ds = |\lambda'(t)|dt$

Comment: $d\vec r$ is different from $ds$. You can think of $ds$ as the magnitude of $d\vec r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I studied analysis about twenty years ago, so my answer should be considered not as a rigor proof but as an idea.

$$\int_\lambda f\ ds = \int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\frac{ds}{dt}dt.$$

Let $\lambda(t)=(\lambda_x(t), \lambda_y(t))$. Then 
$ds=\sqrt{\lambda_x’^2+\lambda_y’^2}dt=\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2 t}dt$,

$$\int_\lambda f\ ds=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}\cdot 
\sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2 t}dt=$$

Now let’s try to find

$$I=\int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}\cdot \sqrt{a^2\sin^2t+b^2\cos^2 t}dt$$

To get rid of trigonometric functions, make a substitution $u=\tan t$. Then $\cos^2 t=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2 t}=\frac{1}{1+u^2}$, $\sin^2 t=\frac{\tan^2 t}{1+\tan^2 t}=\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$, $t=\operatorname{atan} u$, and $dt=\frac {du}{1+u^2}$. Hence

$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2u^2}\cdot \sqrt{a^2u^2+b^2}}{(1+u^2)^2}du.$$

Then I used for references a fundamental and huge (it has more than two thousand pages in three volumes) book “Differential and Integral Calculus” by Grigorii Fichtenholz. There is written that such integrals are called *(pseudo)elliptic* and usually cannot be expressed in a finite form by elementary functions even with the extended meaning of this term. Mathcad failed to calculate $I$ too.

*Update*. If we interpret the given integral as

$$\int_\lambda f\ dr =\int_\lambda f\ d\lambda= \int_0^{2\pi} f(t)\frac{d\lambda}{dt}dt.$$

then the calculations become simple. Indeed, let

$\lambda(t)=(\lambda_x(t), \lambda_y(t))$. Then 
$d\lambda=(\lambda_x’,\lambda_y’)dt=(-a\sin t, b\cos t)dt$,

$$\int_\lambda f\ dr=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}\cdot 
(-a\sin t, b\cos t)dt.$$

Now let’s try to find

$$I=\int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}\cdot (-a\sin t, b\cos t)dt=(I_1,I_2),$$

where 
$$I_1=\int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}(-a\sin t)dt,$$

and $$I_2=\int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}(b\cos t)dt.$$

But

$$I_1=\int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}\cdot a\cdot d\cos t=
a\int \sqrt{(a^2-b^2)u^2 + b^2}du,$$

and

$$I_2=\int \sqrt{a^2\cos^2 t + b^2\sin^2 t}\cdot b\cdot d\sin t=
b\int \sqrt{(b^2-a^2)u^2 + a^2}du$$

At last I recall the standard integrals

$$\int \sqrt{\alpha t^2+\beta}\cdot dt=\frac 12t\sqrt{\alpha t^2+\beta}+\frac{\beta}2\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\alpha t^2+\beta}},$$

and 
$$\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\alpha t^2+\beta}}=\cases{ 
\frac 1{\sqrt{\alpha}}\ln\left|t+\sqrt{t^2+\frac{\beta}{\alpha}}\right|+C,\mbox{ if }\alpha>0 \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\alpha|}}\operatorname{asin} \left(\sqrt{\frac{|\alpha|}{\beta}}t \right)+C,\mbox{ if }\alpha<0}.$$

Comment: But should the integral be $\cdot \lambda'(t)$ or $|\lambda'(t)|$? I think its the latter, I must have mistaken

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs As I have already noted, I'm not sure in my interpretation of $\int_\lambda f ds$, so you may check the definition. Based on the comments I have used the latter.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs But in the first case the integral should be simple, see the update.